# IE 9 in IE8 Browser Mode/Document mode supports SVG?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, raphael, internet-explorer-9

I just upgraded to IE9 to do cross browser compatibility testing of my site, which uses Raphael.js. I know my site and its Raphael.js graphics work in IE8 proper using VML, but for some reason, when I set IE9 to have IE8 Browser Mode/Document Mode, Raphael.js tries to use SVG instead of VML. This doesn't happen when I set IE9 to IE7 Browser Mode/Document Mode; that is, Rapahel.js uses VML. Why does IE9 think that IE8 supported SVG?

Comment: The problem seems to be that `win.SVGAngle` is defined in IE9's IE8 mode, but isn't in normal IE8.

Comment: This doesn't appear to reproduce in the latest internal build. Is there a URL I could try?

Comment: I don't have a URL with that anymore, but the line of code from Raphael.js is here: https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/master/raphael.js#L92 - window.SVGAngle was defined for me in IE9's IE8 mode... I'm not on my PC right now so I can't tell you which version I have... but I can check on Monday.

Comment: IE9 RC improved [other discrepancies](http://ajh.us/test-inline-block) between IE8 and IE9-in-IE8-mode. Does this issue persist as of February’s IE9 Release Candidate?

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Raphaël, but I do know that IE9 reports its JScript Version incorrectly. No matter what version you have Browser Mode/Document Mode set to, @_jscript_version returns 9. If Raphaël decides whether to use VML or SVG based on @_jscript_version, it could cause trouble.

Comment: Hmm that's not quite it... this is the line that's tripping up IE: `R.type = (win.SVGAngle || doc.implementation.hasFeature("http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#BasicStructure", "1.1") ? "SVG" : "VML");` so in IE8, `win.SVGAngle` isn't defined, but it seems like IE9's IE8 mode has it defined...